# file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, digital-ocean

This is my function it works in my computer but when I run this on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server it gives me `file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty` error

```
public function uploadFile($request)
{
    $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file('profile_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image = $request->file('profile_photo');
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($request->file('profile_photo')), 'public');
    return $imageName;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I tried multiple ways but none of them work. I copied this code from my existing projects it works there even in my local machine but not working in digital ocean ububntu server. I think some configuration issues

Comment: I have the same issue. Its probably some configuration issue. File_get_contents returns empty on digitalocean ubuntu server. It works fine on my localhost and namecheap hosting. I am migrating my site to namecheap now.  You should probably try out other hosting companies.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this structure to store the photo instead:

```php
public function uploadFile($request)
{
    $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file('profile_photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $path = $request->profile_photo->storeAs('public', $imageName, 's3');

    return $imageName;
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer - what have you changed, and why?